# How does min_doc_freq work in More Like This Query

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

I've some parts of documents with the following structure:

```
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Dupieux" } ]
```

And my **More Like This** query is the following:

```
"_source": [ "directors.name" ],
"query": {
  "more_like_this": {
    "fields": [ "directors.name" ],
    "like": "quentin tarantino",
    "min_term_freq": 1,
    "min_doc_freq": 9
  }
}
```

I usnderstand if i use `"min_doc_freq": 7` then, in this sample, the query only should retrieve one document `"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Dupieux" } ]` is it corret?

But, the query retrieves only 3 documents:

```
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Tarantino" } ]
"directors": [ { "name": "Quentin Dupieux" } ]
```

I don't understand why..
Can anyone tell me why the query retrieves only 3 "documents"

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to replicate your query. I am getting all documents with "min_term_freq": 1, and  min_doc_freq :7/9. Can you tell what is count of documents with Quentin Tarantino and Quentin Dupieux. Can you also check if your query is complete and correct

Comment: Thanks, for your comment, i have **10** documents with **Quentin Tarantino** and **1** document with **Quentin Dupieux**. I think the query is completed and correct.

I uso Elasticsearch 7.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my mistake, i needed to set the number of shards  in 1 for elasticsearch 7.6.2 and for elasticsearch 7.4.2 i set the number of shards and number of replicas in 1 in the index creation. Defaults values

`"number_of_shards": 1`

`"number_of_replicas": 1`

Thanks!